# Delete Playlist Item in Youtube using API v3

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to delete the Playlist Item (Video) in Playlist, If i pass the Playlist ID and Playlist Item ID (Video ID), Its throwing a error, i Can't delete the particular video in that playlist, pls help me to solve this issue

An client error occurred: (delete) missing required param : 'id'

```
$playlistItemResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->delete($_GET['videoid'],$playlistItem);
```

Answer (score 3):

First, use the [`youtube.playlistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) to list all the videos in the specific playlist. Just pass the `playlistId` of the playlist that you want to get.

Here's the sample request for that:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&playlistId=PLgTC0orxjF5MrSEDzjT7J1lkR4zYwPEpf&_h=1&

And here is the Json response

[image]

My playlist is composed of three videos

[image]

Now, to delete a video in the Playlist, you need to use the [`youtube.playlistItems.delete`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete).

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.delete?id=&_h=1&

The id that you will put there is the id that you will get in the Json response. For example, in the above Json picture, to delete the video **Kobe Bryant's Top 10 Deep Three-Pointers** you need to pass the id **"UExnVEMwb3J4akY1TXJTRUR6alQ3SjFsa1I0ell3UEVwZi4wMTcyMDhGQUE4NTIzM0Y5"** in the [`youtube.playlistItems.delete`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete)

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: but how can i do this in PHP ? what are the parameters can i pass ?

Comment: playlistId, check the link that I gave. You will understand more about this.

Comment: iam trying to add  this script to delete the playlist item id, bit its asking login required...    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
   var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.delete({                    
              id: item.id
          });
   request.execute(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
      });
   
                });